# Parsing complex forms using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an e-commerce site that is selling to multiple countries.

We have to charge different prices for the same product in different countries due to shipping costs etc,

We also have different attributes for different products (such as size, color, etc,.).

I am using PHP to generate a form for pricing products like this.

My PHP is as follows:

```
    $attribute = $_GET['attribute'];
    $params = [$attribute];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
    $attributeCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($attributeCount > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $attribute_name = $row["name"];
        }
    }
    $price_form .= "<table class='table'>";
    $price_form .= "<thead>";
    $price_form .= "<td>$attribute_name</td>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql);
    $countryCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($countryCount > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $country_name = $row["country"];
            $price_form .= "<td>$country_name</td>";
        }
    }
    $price_form .= "</thead>";
    $params = [$attribute];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
    $attributeResult = DB::run($sql,$params);
    foreach ($attributeResult as $value) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
            $attributeColumn = "attribute".$i;
            $checkbox = "checkbox".$i;
            $priceValue = "priceValue".$i;
            $priceCurrency = "priceCurrency".$i;
            $priceAttribute = "priceAttribute".$i;
            if($value[$attributeColumn] != ""){
                $price_form .= "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='$checkbox' id='$checkbox' value='$checkbox'";
                if($attribute == 1){ $price_form .= " checked";}
                $price_form .= ">$value[$attributeColumn]</td>";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
                $countryResult = DB::run($sql);
                while ($row = $countryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $country_id = $row["id"];
                    $country_currency = $row["currency"];
                    $price_form .= '<td>';
                    $price_form .= '<input type="text" placeholder='.$country_currency.' name='.$priceValue.'_'.$country_id.' size="10">';
                    $price_form .= '<input type="hidden" value='.$country_id.' name='.$priceCurrency.'_'.$country_id.'>';
                    $price_form .= '<input type="hidden" value='.$i.' name='.$priceAttribute.'_'.$country_id.'>';
                    $price_form .= '</td>';
                }
            }
            $price_form .= '</tr>';
        }
    }
    $price_form .= "</table>";
    $price_form .= "<br />";
    $price_form .= "<button id='add_prices' name='add_prices' onClick='return false'>Continue</button>";
```

This results in something like this depending on the attribute the product has, in this case, color:

```html
<table class="table"><thead><tr><td>Colour</td><td>Ireland</td><td>United Kingdom</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1">Black</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue1_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency1_1"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceAttribute1_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue1_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency1_2"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceAttribute1_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2">White</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue2_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency2_1"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceAttribute2_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue2_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency2_2"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceAttribute2_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="checkbox3">Purple</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue3_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency3_1"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="priceAttribute3_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue3_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency3_2"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="priceAttribute3_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" value="checkbox4">Yellow</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue4_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency4_1"><input type="hidden" value="4" name="priceAttribute4_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue4_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency4_2"><input type="hidden" value="4" name="priceAttribute4_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" value="checkbox5">Red</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue5_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency5_1"><input type="hidden" value="5" name="priceAttribute5_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue5_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency5_2"><input type="hidden" value="5" name="priceAttribute5_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" value="checkbox6">Orange</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue6_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency6_1"><input type="hidden" value="6" name="priceAttribute6_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue6_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency6_2"><input type="hidden" value="6" name="priceAttribute6_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" id="checkbox7" value="checkbox7">Blue</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue7_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency7_1"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="priceAttribute7_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue7_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency7_2"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="priceAttribute7_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8" value="checkbox8">Green</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue8_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency8_1"><input type="hidden" value="8" name="priceAttribute8_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue8_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency8_2"><input type="hidden" value="8" name="priceAttribute8_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9" value="checkbox9">Pink</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue9_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency9_1"><input type="hidden" value="9" name="priceAttribute9_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue9_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency9_2"><input type="hidden" value="9" name="priceAttribute9_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" id="checkbox10" value="checkbox10">Grey</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue10_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency10_1"><input type="hidden" value="10" name="priceAttribute10_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue10_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency10_2"><input type="hidden" value="10" name="priceAttribute10_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox11" id="checkbox11" value="checkbox11">Brown</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue11_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency11_1"><input type="hidden" value="11" name="priceAttribute11_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue11_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency11_2"><input type="hidden" value="11" name="priceAttribute11_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox12" id="checkbox12" value="checkbox12">Spearmint</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue12_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency12_1"><input type="hidden" value="12" name="priceAttribute12_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue12_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency12_2"><input type="hidden" value="12" name="priceAttribute12_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox13" id="checkbox13" value="checkbox13">Lime Green</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue13_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency13_1"><input type="hidden" value="13" name="priceAttribute13_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue13_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency13_2"><input type="hidden" value="13" name="priceAttribute13_2"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

We have a load of attribute sets for colors sizes etc but not all of them might apply to certain products that are the purpose of the checkbox.

I had been parsing this through PHP but the whole section for adding a product in its entirety was getting very complex not just the pricing. (different sections were being submitted, saved in a `$_SESSION` so it could be stored while other sections were being submitted, and then submitting all `$_SESSION` variables when each section was complete.

However I've switched to AJAX so the page isn't refreshing the whole time and I don't need to keep storing `$_SESSION` variables.

My PHP was as follows:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    $checkbox = "checkbox".$i;
    $priceValue = "priceValue".$i;
    $priceCurrency = "priceCurrency".$i;
    $priceAttribute = "priceAttribute".$i;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $countryCount; $j++) {
        $priceValue1 = $priceValue.'_'.$j;
        $priceCurrency1 = $priceCurrency.'_'.$j;
        $priceAttribute1 = $priceAttribute.'_'.$j;
        if(isset($_SESSION[''.$priceValue1.'']) && isset($_SESSION[''.$priceCurrency1.'']) && isset($_SESSION[''.$priceAttribute1.''])){
            $value = $_SESSION[''.$priceValue1.''];
            $currency = $_SESSION[''.$priceCurrency1.''];
            $attribute = $_SESSION[''.$priceAttribute1.''];
            $params = [$id,$currency,$attribute,$value];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO prices (product, country, attribute, value) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I want to parse this with AJAX I'm not sure how to loop through all of these without knowing the `$countryCount` variable from `PHP` to determine how many countries are stored (we want this to be dynamic so we can expand into more countries).

I've tried messing around with loops inside loops (one loop for attributes and one for countries) but I'm getting nowhere, there has to be a better way of doing this without having to hard code out getting the value of each price for each country.

### Edit

So far I've been trying to push them all into a multidimensional array like this:

```
var pricing = [];
for (i = 0; i <15; i++) {
    var checkbox = "checkbox"+i;
    var priceValue = "priceValue"+i;
    var priceCurrency = "priceCurrency"+i;
    var priceAttribute = "priceAttribute"+i;
    if ($("#"+checkbox).is(':checked')) {
        for (j = 1; j <=2; j++) {
            var priceValue1 = priceValue+'_'+j;
            var priceCurrency1 = priceCurrency+'_'+j;
            var priceAttribute1 = priceAttribute+'_'+j;
            var value = $("#"+priceValue1).val();
            var currency = $("#"+priceCurrency1).val();
            var attribute = $("#"+priceAttribute1).val();
            var item = [];
            item.push(value);
            item.push(currency);
            item.push(attribute);
            pricing.push(i);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is wrong and giving me errors.

It is also not dynamic enough, in the second for() loop I just put in '2' for the amount of countries for the time being.

Comment: Note that each table cell with an input in the snippet above also has two hidden fields. So each cell has 3 inputs. One to reference the attribute ID, one for the country ID, and the actual input you see for the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to send it as form data or in sessions? I think it is better to create a JSON object that contains what you want in a sensible manner. Then stringify and send it and then parse it in the php side and get the object. This way you are not limited to the formdata requirements.

Second, and more importantly, whatever you do, dont use the values that come directly. It is wiser to regenerate and recalculate data based on an intermediate transmitted data that is harder to forge. You should always be able to check whether the data is valid, or you'll be in trouble sooner or later.

P.S. You can iterate on an array from json like this:

```
$arr = json_decode('[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]');

foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $uses = $item['var1']; //etc
}
```

Comment: I think the $_SESSION is no longer needed, this was there originally so that when one section submitted and the page refreshed I could keep all of these variables until all sections had been submitted. I now want to send them via AJAX so there is no need for page refresh. I don't mind if it is a$_SESSION, form data, or json object. I think the main part that I am struggling with is looping through the inputs in a logical way to get all of the inputs into variables or a JSON object.

Comment: Check the p.s.!

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I'm not sure I'm explaining myself the best. I would have no problem parsing the JSON object in PHP it is looping through the form inputs to create the JSON object to begin with that I am having the issue with. I'm just having difficulty with all of the hidden inputs as well and looping through these to put the variables into an array/json object in a logical way that makes sense.